# Does S3 Strong Consistency mean it is safe to use S3 as a checkpointing location for Spark Structured Streaming applications?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-structured-streaming

In the past, the general consensus was such that you should not use S3 as checkpointing location for Spark Structured Streaming applications.

However, now that S3 offers [strong read after write consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/), is it safe to use S3 as a checkpointing location? If it is not safe, why?

In my experiments, I continue to see checkpointing related exceptions in my Spark Structured streaming applications, but I am uncertain where the problem actually lies.

Comment: What exceptions r u seeing?

Comment: Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431120/error-reading-delta-file-from-spark-structured-streaming

Using Spark 3.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not really. you get consistency of list and updates, but rename is still mocked with copy and delete...and I think the standard checkpoint algorithm depends on it.

hadoop 3.3.1 added a new API, `Abortable` to aid with a custom S3 stream checkpoint committer -the idea os that the checkpointer woudl write sstraight to the destination, but abort the write when aborting the checkpoint. a normal close() would finish the write and manifest the file. see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16906

AFAIK nobody has done the actual committer. opportunity for you to contribute there...

Answer (score 0):

You really answer your own question. You do not state if on Databricks or EMR so I am going to assume EC2.

Use HDFS as checkpoint location on local EC2 disk.

Where I am now we have HDFS using HDP and IBM S3, HDFS is used still for checkpointing.

Comment: The question is not about hdfs. I know using hdfs works, the question is about S3, and why it can or cannot be used as checkpointing location given that s3 consistency issues have been resolved

Comment: But the answer still holds and u answer it yourself.